# Template arguments can evaluate c-style array parameter but not std::array

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm inputting an array of strings to a function to evaluate an output with vector of the same length. The primary motivation behind this is so structured bindings can be used on the output as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>

template <std::size_t N>
void get_array_vals_impl(std::string(&& valueNames)[N], std::vector<std::array<std::string, N>>& results)
{
    // populates results. Passed in as param as it is called recursively iterating over a directory
}

template <std::size_t N>
std::vector<std::array<std::string, N>> get_array_vals(std::string(&& valueNames)[N])
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, N>> res;
    get_array_vals_impl(valueNames, res);
    return res;
}

template <std::size_t N>
std::vector<std::array<std::string, N>> get_array_vals(std::string(&valueNames)[N])
{
    return get_array_vals(valueNames);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    auto res1 = get_array_vals({ "test"s, "second_arg"s });

    for (auto const& [first, second] : res1)
    {
        // use first and second accordingly. compile-time errors if structured binding length
        // doesn't match the length of the input arguments.
    }

    std::string another_test[] = { "hi", "hello" };

    auto res2 = get_array_vals(another_test); // also works fine
}
```

However, when I try to use std::array as the input, it fails with `no instance of overloaded function "get_array_vals" matches the argument list`.
why can't `std::array<std::string, 2>` be evaluated in this instance? Would I really need to add another overload for this instance?

Comment: Why do you think `std::array<std::string, N>` is implicitly convertible to `std::string(&)[N]`?

Comment: c-style arrays and `std::array` are 2 different types, with no real relationship even if one is just a wrapper of the other. So yes, you need to make an overload or use some template magic to write generic code that accepts both. Probably much easier with an overload.

Comment: @theWiseBro I'd assume seeing as it's a compile-time constructed array in the same manner that a c-style array is, I don't really see the conflict for making it implicitly convertible?

Comment: @PCresswell it isn't that it can't be made convertible, but rather that it shouldn't be made convertible. It is DANGEROUS. One should never expect a data type A to be implicitely be casted to a data type B just because they serve similar purpose or are similar.